# Cannot Find Httpd Configuration Value in httpd.conf (Amazon AWS EC2)

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using free tier Amazon AWS EC2 micro instance and hosting a Wordpress site. As the memory is too low, I always get common error like "Error Establishing to Database", and from the log I can see that the http process takes the memory.This causes the web service to be stopped.

I have tuned my MySQL config file and now I like to tune up the http configuration. I like to apply the things below in my httpd.conf

```
Timeout 30
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 50
KeepAliveTimeout 10

<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers          3
    MinSpareServers       2
    MaxSpareServers       5
    MaxClients            10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
```

But for some reason, I could not find the info above in the file. Do I need to add it manually? Is it in somewhere else? I have tried to find it in another folder but could not find anything. I am not a Linux guy by the way. I appreciate any guidance on this.

My Linux version is Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03. Thanks.

Comment: Did you finally find a good tuning? May you share your mysql config file as well or any link to know how? Did all these tuning give you a good result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing for you would be to add your configuration file and monitor `httpd` after restart.

Comment: OK let me just put it in the `httpd.conf` file and see how it goes. Just to check if the location to put is correct.

Comment: For regular linux, its location is usually `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 2):

Main configuration file:

```
- /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Other configuration loaded files:

```
- conf.modules.d/*.conf
- conf.d/*.conf
```

MPM Configuration file:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf
```

You couldn't find the section  cause Amazon uses the default configuration. Add your code in the end of this file:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
 StartServers 3
 MinSpareServers 2
 MaxSpareServers 5
 ServerLimit 10
 MaxClients 10
 MaxRequestsPerChild 100
</IfModule>
```

and restart Apache server:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Source: https://www.pauloacosta.com/2019/09/onde-fica-o-arquivo-de-configuracao-do.html